# Partition of measure-preserving dynamical system.

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

We have given a measure-preserving dynamical system $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$, where $T:X\to X$ is measurable transformation which preserves the measure $\mu$, i.e. $\forall_{A\in\mathcal{B}} \ \mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$. Then in such space we take a partition, i.e. finite or countable set $\xi$ of nonempty measurable pair-wise disjoint subsets of X, for which $\bigcup_{A\in\xi}A=X$.
My question sounds: if that subsets in $\xi$ must have a positive measure? Can we take also a subsets which the measure $\mu$ is equal to zero (e.i. can $\xi$ consists some $B$, for which $\mu(B)=0$)? In other words whether the partition $\xi$ is understood $\mu$-almost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can also have sets of measure zero, provided that when you use the partition for something specific you "deal with them". For example, with the **convention** that $0\log0=0$ you can compute the entropy of the partition.

So, really it doesn't matter: you can either say that sets of measure zero are allowed or forbid them.

Another approach is to consider equivalence classes of partitions$\bmod0$ in the sense that two partitions are equivalent if for each set $A$ of one of them you can find a set $B$ in the other such that the symmetric difference $A\Delta B$ has measure zero.

For example, you can then define the entropy of the equivalence class as the entropy of any element of the class. Similar observations apply to many other concepts.

Comment: I just using this concepts to define a measure entropy of transformation $T:X\to X$ :) So ok, I will be understand the partition with sets of measure zero.